# ListTile with wrap_content width

Tags: flutter

Now when I add a `ListTile` inside a view (no matter  its `Column,ListView,...`) It gets whole width, I want it to be kinda `wrap_content` as we have in android.

Comment: Please don't suggetst to use `SizedBox`

Comment: you have to do your own ListTile i guess

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post but here is a solution I found for future reference:

You can use the `IntrinsicWidth` widget to stop the `ListTile` from expanding.

```dart
Container(
  child: IntrinsicWidth(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ListTile(title: Text("Hello")),
        ListTile(title: Text("There")),
      ],
    )
  )
)
```

As far as I can tell this is not how you are supposed to use `ListTile`. In the docs it even says:

> ListTile requires fixed width constraints

Also, regarding `IntrinsicWidth` the docs say:

> This class is useful, for example, when unlimited width is available and you would like a child that would otherwise attempt to expand infinitely to instead size itself to a more reasonable width. [...] This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible.

Answer (score 0):

may be like this

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(),
        Text("hell")
])
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!